# Godot как описать тип данных?

Tags: godot

Делаю игру. У меня 6 планет, на каждой планете живет 1000 людей. У каждого человека должен быть задан пол, возраст, профессия и т.п.
Как в GODOT описать структуру и присвоить шести разным переменным?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос неточен. Как я понял вы спрашиваете про ООП. В GDScript это делается вот так: https://youtu.be/BAmQ_jC_kZ0

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]